# Why there are no Triage and Help & Improvement queues?

Tags: discussion

In stackoverflow there are two other additional review queues;

1. Triage
2. Help and Improvement

Why those queues are not in this community? Because low traffic compared to Stackoverflow and all of them can be handled in the low quality posts queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the main factor is the difference in scale: 7800 questions per day on Stack Overflow, versus 45 on Ethereum.  This was discussed in [Triage and Help & Improvement review queues at sites other than Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251737/triage-and-help-improvement-review-queues-at-sites-other-than-stack-overflow) where a Stack Exchange employee wrote:

> Triage itself is probably pointless on all but the very largest sites. The whole point is to chew through a huge number of questions as quickly as possible; if you're only getting a few dozen questions per day, it's unlikely that there are enough reviewers to make it work or enough questions to keep them interested in the first place.

Both Triage and Help & Improvement are designed for the situation where nobody can see what is happening on the site just by looking at the front page, because everything drops off in a matter of seconds. Only Stack Overflow is currently in that situation.